# Problema entre PagSeguro e número de parcelas

Tags: php, javascript

Fiz a implementação de uma loja virtual customizada na linguagem PHP e como checkout estou utilizando **PagSeguro**.

Na implementação foi utilizado o checkout transparente e estava funcionando corretamente, porém o cliente solicitou que seja adicionada a opção de parcelamento do pedido. Ao tentar realizar a requisição de parcelas utilizando a *API Javascript*, a resposta é sempre a mesma:

> {"errors":{"SESSÃO inválida:
> d4d905b585ec4d4d8056e380df70e4a5.":"10005"},"error":true}

Para fazer essa requisição estou utilizando o seguinte método Javascript:

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getInstallments
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda para solucionar, pois como disse anteriormente o checkout estava funcionando corretamente e a única alteração realizada foi a adição do parcelamento.

---

Métodos utilizados

Retorno do getSessionId

> {"result":true,"data":"b099c6f4beff41e0a08a4912f7ce9554"}

Busca bandeira do cartão

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand({
    cardBin: $scope.pagamento.cartao,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response && response.brand && response.brand.name) {
            $scope.bandeira = response.brand.name;
            $scope.getParcelasCartao();
        }
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Busca dos meios de pagamento

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getInstallments({
    amount: valor,
    maxInstallmentNoInterest: 2,
    brand: $scope.bandeira,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.error == false) {
            $scope.parcelamento = response.installments[$scope.bandeira];
        }
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.parcelamento = new Array();
    },
    complete: function(response) {

    }
});
```

Parametros que são enviados na requisição para buscar o parcelamento

> sessionId: b099c6f4beff41e0a08a4912f7ce9554
>
> amount: 49.90
>
> creditCardBrand: visa
>
> maxInstallmentNoInterest: 2

Retorno da busca:

> {"errors":{"SESSÃO inválida: b099c6f4beff41e0a08a4912f7ce9554.":"10005"},"error":true}

Comment: Se puder, poste parte do seu código para nos ajudar a lhe ajudar :)

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeNagatomo, obrigado pela sugestão. Já adicionei as informações e os parâmetros enviados em cada requisição lembrando que estou utilizando a API Javascript do PagSeguro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fiz recentemente uma integração com o PagSeguro transparente, e me deparei com essa e outras dificuldades.

Supondo q vc esteja usando a biblioteca oficial deles no PHP (https://github.com/pagseguro/php), segue abaixo os problemas encontrados e como foram resolvidos, começando pelo que eu acredito ser a causa do seu problema (claro que para ter certeza há a necessidade de ver o código PHP):

**maxInstallmentNoInterest**

> Um erro comum é enviar um campo ao PS pelo JS e não fazer o mesmo pelo PHP. O problema é que no caso específico deste campo, a biblioteca não possui um atributo próprio para enviá-lo, sendo necessário fazer o uso de **addParameter**, dessa forma: `$psRequest->addParameter('noInterestInstallmentQuantity', 2);`

**Nome do Banco**

> Para pagamentos via Débito Online (EFT), há a necessidade de se informar o nome do banco, algo que não fica claro no manual. Para isso, utilize o método **setOnlineDebit**, dessa forma: `$psRequest->setOnlineDebit(array("bankName" => 'nome do banco');`

**EFT vs ONLINE_DEBIT**

> O método do JS **getPaymentMethods** retorna um JSON cuja nomenclatura para pagamentos online é **ONLINE_DEBIT**. Porém, na biblioteca do PHP essa nomenclatura muda para **EFT**. A classe do PHP onde isso se encontra é a PagSeguroDirectPaymentMethods, e uma das formas de corrigir esse conflito é por adicionar a seguinte linha na declaração do atributo **$methodsList**: `"ONLINE_DEBIT" => "eft",`

Espero que estas sugestões possam lhe ajudar a finalizar o seu projeto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Szag-Ot, o problema nesse caso era o Javascript. Como estava utilizando a API em sandbox o javascript deveria vir do sandbox também.
Acho meio falho esse método pois pode ocorrer um monte de erros por esquecimento.
Problema que na documentação não diz nada disso rsrs.
Mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Ainda nem saí do PagSeguroDirectPayment.getBrand, já cai direto no error com Object {error : true}, estou passando '411111' (6 primeiros dígitos do cartão de crédito da SandBox). Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @JhonatanPereira não entendi sua dúvida.... poderia postar o erro que está dando ou parte do código? Talvez seria melhor criar uma nova questão para isso

Comment: É que é um problema tão curto... Como você já conhece o código, deixei bem resumido: https://jsfiddle.net/jpdesignerrio/drhdomng/2/

Comment: Caso não dê pra saber o porquê do erro, e porque ele não retorna o motivo do erro, abro uma nova questão

Comment: @JhonatanPereira o trecho do codigo postado está correto... porem vc sabe que o getBrand deve ser continuação de outro método, né? O getPaymentMethods. Segue link com trecho do código que uso em nosso sistema, espero que ajude: http://codepen.io/szagot/pen/RRdXVY?editors=0010

Comment: Obrigado @Szag-Ot

Comment: Cara, estou recebendo o erro 59001 : "unknown web session id" e não acho solução pra ele! Já abri novo tópico aqui no Stack há 3 dias, mas até agora ninguém respondeu... Sabe me dizer o motivo do erro?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148507/pagseguro-getpaymentmethods-erro/148773#148773

Comment: verificando, @JhonatanPereira

Comment: O problema era o navegador, funcionou. Só não sei o que mais preciso fazer depois da função que pega o Token do Cartão