# PagSeguro getPaymentMethods Erro

Tags: javascript, jquery

> 59001 - "unknown web session id"

Estou implementando Checkout Transparente do PagSeguro usando API PHP v2, porém sempre recebo o erro acima na parte do JavaScript. O suporte deles é horrível, não há mais onde recorrer.

**Editado:** Adicionei o link real, para que testes possam ser realizados.

[**Download dos Arquivos**](http://www.plimplimfestas.com/rafael/stack.rar)

Segue o código:

```js
function cartao(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var senderHash;
 $.post('http://plimplimfestas.com/rafael/checkout.php', { sessao: "sessao" }, function(returnedData){
    //TESTES
    //*******************************************//
 //***** Inicializando a sessão checkout *****//  //*******************************************//
 var xml = returnedData,
 xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
 $xml = $(xmlDoc),
 $title = $xml.find("id");
  
 var idSess = $title.text();
 console.log("SessionId");
    console.log(idSess);
    PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId(idSess);
      
    //***************************************//
    //***** Obtendo o hash do comprador *****//
    //***************************************//
    var hashComprador = PagSeguroDirectPayment.getSenderHash();
    senderHash = hashComprador;
    //FIM TESTES
  }).done(function(){
    PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
    success: function(response){ console.log(response); },
    error: function(response){ console.log(response); },
    complete: function(response){ console.log(response); }
   });
   throw "Stop forçado.";
      //Os consoles de error e complete acima retornam o erro
      /*
      existem mais trechos, porém não passa do ponto acima
      */
      
      }).fail(function(e){
   console.error(e);
   });
   }); //document ready
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao que parece, ele não está reconhecendo a Session ID usada. Como você está fazendo pra obter o Id da Sessão?

O correto, que deve ser feito do lado do servidor, seria algo assim (exemplo em PHP, usando o SDK deles):

```
$credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();    
$idSession = PagSeguroSessionService::getSession($credentials);
```

Aí, no JS, vc recepciona esse dado. Se o seu código PHP estiver junto com o JS (não recomendado, porém este exemplo é apenas para fins de esclarecimento), você pode fazer algo assim:

```
var idSess = '<?= $idSession ?>';
```

Se não for este o caso, passe o código onde você pega o ID da Sessão

Obs.: Link de exemplo para o JS:http://codepen.io/szagot/pen/RRdXVY?editors=0010

Comment: Adiciona o link http://codepen.io/szagot/pen/RRdXVY?editors=0010 na sua resposta, pois sem isso eu ainda estaria perdido haha Tudo funcionando, valeu!

Comment: @JhonatanPereira - Colocado ;)

Answer (score -1):

Isso realmente não está descrito na documentação, triste...

Depois de obter o ID da sessão através da API vc deve setar ele no objeto da lib do PagSeguro

PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('d2bd8672814kkkkkka67b44e872172')

depois pode chamar os outros métodos tranquilo :D

Answer (score -1):

Cara eu tive esse erro fiquei horas tentando resolver e não sabia o que era, irei colocar aqui o que acabou acontecendo comigo, mas possa ser que o seu erro seja por outro motivo.

Quando estava vendo a documentação acabei pegando o link informado na documentação, o link da lib de js do pagSeguro que seria o link a baixo.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src=
"https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"></script>
```

mas como o meu ambiente era de teste nunca iria dar certo, pois este link é de produção, então era só por o link a baixo

```html
https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js
```

Bem esse foi o meu problema, só uma falta de atenção mesmo, espero que ajude outras pessoas!

Answer (score -2):

Todas as requisições de URL no documento de produção devem conter HTTPS(SSL), exceto na fase de desenvolvimento sandbox.